# Magento API times out after 60 seconds

Tags: php, performance, magento, nginx

I'm using Magento API V2 and facing what seems to be a time-out issue during an update of a product which is linked to 800 categories. I'm using the method catalogProductUpdate. The call times out after exactly 60 seconds. I've looked around and found many suggestion on how to increase time limits, but none of them worked in my case. I've increased the nginx, php and mysql time-outs, but it didn't help. My nginx http settings:

```
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 200;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_body_timeout 2m;
    client_header_timeout 2m;
    send_timeout 2m;
```

When i decrease the number of categories to 500 categories, it all works fine. So really seems like a time limit somewhere in the system. I also tried to update the product on a different system and a copy of the database, gave me the same problem. Any clue where i should look further? Is there maybe a Magento time-out i don't know of?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have the `max_execution_time` set to 60 on the server where your magento instance is installed.
take a look in `php.ini` and change it if needed.
Set it to 0 to never timeout.

Comment: I have already tried to increase the max_execution_time but it didn't help. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same call on an a old backup of the same database and it worked very fast. I guess the database got corrupt. I'll look into how this could happen and how to avoid it in the future. Thanks everyone.